# How to fill custom shape/path using EaselJS

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I am exploring CreateJS. This question concerns EaselJS.

I have managed to draw 3 arcs and fill them with a color.

[image]

Although, I want the final result to look like this:

[image]

If I draw a triangle to fill the missing space, how can I remove the color inside the bottom arc?

If I set it to `transparent` it will display the triangle color.
I could set it to white to look like what I want in this case, but it would look bad on top of a colored background.

Is there any method in the API that I am missing in order to do something similar to a flood fill inside a shape drawn with multiple arcs/lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of drawing three separate arcs, you should use arcTo to keep the path continuous.

Something like this (of course replacing the numbers with your points/control points):

```
new Graphics().beginStroke(STROKE_COLOR)
    .moveTo(0, 20)
    .arcTo(150, 20, 150, 70, 50)
    .arcTo(150, 20, 150, 70, 50)
    .arcTo(150, 20, 150, 70, 50)
    .endStroke();
```